# Consolidate SQL Table Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named tblCustomerproductsstatus which is feeded through an automated data processing engine.
It contains columns like - *TradeID, CustomerInfoNo,  product, Status, ProductQuantity, BoughtDate...* as shown below.

```
TradeID  CustomerNo Product Name    Status   ProductQuantity     BoughtDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
320046  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 4/16/2015
324825  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 4/17/2015
326673  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 4/18/2015
337943  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 4/19/2015
337944  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    180 4/20/2015
344243  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    180 4/21/2015
350815  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    180 4/22/2015
360105  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    180 4/23/2015
362186  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 4/24/2015
368117  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 4/25/2015
376820  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 4/26/2015
380321  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 4/27/2015
385615  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    255 4/28/2015
386136  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    377 4/29/2015
398302  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    377 4/30/2015
387825  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 5/1/2015
388088  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 5/2/2015
389001  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 5/3/2015
391003  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 5/4/2015
----
----
----**
```

I'm supposed to get results in such a way, as shown below.

```
TradeID  CustomerNo Product Name    Status   ProductQuantity     BoughtDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
320046  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 4/16/2015
337944  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    180 4/20/2015
362186  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 4/24/2015
385615  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    255 4/28/2015
386136  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    377 4/29/2015
387825  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    125 5/1/2015
389001  A157BV17034 Martin Mazorra Bonds    Done    170 5/3/2015
----
----
----
```

if a customer buys a product on '4/16/2015' and continues to have it till '4/19/2015' then we only display one initial record with his initial TradeID, and this continues...
I hope i've made myself clear on this.

i've been thinking of using outer apply/ inner joins but not sure what to do.

I may need to run this query through **OPENROWSET** for remote servers, so please, anybody have any suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: you could first try to get all the distinct quantities for a user and then with those distinct quantities get all the records with the lowest date value

Comment: i cant use 'group by' Productquantity', because he bought 125 again on May 1st.

Comment: So you dont have any other field to groupby than Quantity?

Comment: i cant groupby quantity only, don't forget i have to consider tradeID and bought date.

Comment: @JeremyC. I can't do that, please look at result set. on May 1st be has 125 again, so it should be new record to display. IF i use distinct quantity, this wont happen.

Comment: do you have the option to use a stored procedure or does it have to be straight up sql? otherwise you could just order your table by date, read every line and if the value of your quantity changes write it to a resultset or a new table with results

Comment: If you use a combination of temporary tables, stored procedure and inserts in a result table this should be possible but I haven't written a stored procedure in over 2 years so I would need a lot of time to think about specifics, you might even need a cursor because i don't remember if you can run through all records in a table in a stored procedure

Comment: @JeremyC. Yes, i do have access, but is there any other way you can think of?

Comment: not really seeing as the only things you have to work with are the dates, the quantity and the tradeid, and you would always need to keep track of when the quantity changes because you have multiple times where it can have the same value, so regular sql won't do you much good, unless you can split up your table into smaller pieces every time the value is something that it has been before so you can use the top 1  when ordered by quantity,date

Comment: I didn't mean to put this here, I need to learn how this site works properly :p

Comment: @JeremyC. you are absolutely right, what i am trying to achieve is the same, i get lots of logs like this, so i'm trying to minimize the data flow to Clint server in such manner. my final intentions is to make a job which runs the query I'm seeking for. :) - I'm going for a stored procedures, seems that's the optimal solution right now, Thanks.

Comment: no problem, I hope it works out for you, I wish I could help you with the stored procedures but I've been out of those for a while, but I found a link that might be usefull: http://eedle.com/2010/11/11/looping-through-records-in-sql-server-stored-procedure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation, I would use a stored procedure. I have written up a stored procedure that will produce the results you are looking for.

For some reason I can't put the stored procedure in my answer, so you will need to look at the SQL Fiddle.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c977e/14